Creating Laravel Eloquent Relationship
How can i directly get data of Model3 staying from Model1 like hasMayThrough?
I have 3 models and 4 tables



Model 1




id


model2_id






Model 2




id






Model 3




id






PivotTable for Model2 and Model3




model2_id


model3_id




Question incomplete! You have not specified whether model 1 and 2 are connected or not.

@ZaidMalek Please view the above example. Model1 has foreign key i.e model2_id

What have you tried yourself? Why wasn't that working? Do you receive error messages? You should read the "How do I ask a good question?" guide and edit your question accordingly.

Here, You have pivot table means it is many-to-many relationship. In that case you need to use belongsToMany in model2 like below
public function model3relation(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Model3::class);
    }

then you can use
Model1->find(1)->model2->model3relation()->get()


Why would you use Model1->find(1)->model2->model3relation()->get() instead of Model1->find(1)->model2->model3relation ?
